# SCSS override variable in nested class

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to override a variable inside of a nested class in SCSS,

```
$heading-font-family: "OptimusPrincepsB" !default;

.fr{
    $heading-font-family: "TrajanProB"; 
}
```

.fr is a class that is applied to the body if the page is being viewed in French. I want the font family to be different in this case.
This seems more logical to me than going through each header selector with an existing $heading-font-family and overriding it.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the behavior you're expecting?

Comment: why are you trying to override a variable? it seems that you want to use a different font-family for the `.fr` class. just assign another one. makes no sense to override the variable!

Comment: The .fr class is applied to the body when the page is being viewing in French. In which case I want the font to change, I know I could go through and individually find the selectors to change font-family for, however I wondered if there was a faster way and that seemed logical to me. *Sorry should have made more clear in the question.

Comment: To those voting to reopen, could you explain how this is *not* a duplicate of the designated question?